# Is a square commutation matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, permutation-matrices, vectorization

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and denote the commutation matrix, made up of 0 and 1 such that each row and each column has exactly one 1, as $K_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ , which is such that:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{vec}(A^T) = K_{n} \operatorname{vec}(A)
 \end{equation}
It is known (cf. Harville D.A., Matrix Algebra from a Statistician's Perspective) that such a matrix is symmetric,orthogonal, and with determinant $\pm 1$.
Moreover, is it positive semidefinite ?

Comment: If it's always positive definite, the book won't say that its determinant is $\pm1$.

Comment: There is the property that a psd matrix has a non-negative determinant, is that it ? Then $K_n$ is not forcibly psd ?

Comment: thing is that I actually need it to be. My problem is that I want to use the property of determinants : $\det{(A+B)} \geq \det{(A)} + \det{(B)} $ for $A$ and $B$ positive semidefinite matrices. In my case, I would use $A=K_n$ and $B=I_n$.

Comment: @HugoB Well, then the thing you "need" is impossible. Perhaps you should instead post a question about the original problem for which you want to use this inequality.

Comment: @HugoB If all you want is $\det(I_n + K_n)$, then it is easy to see that this determinant will be zero except for $n = 1$.

Comment: Yes, that would be what I'm looking for. Do you have a proof ?

Comment: @Hugo Yes, it suffices to show that $K_n$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue. In particular, if $x = \operatorname{vec}(A)$ with $A^T = -A$ and $A \neq 0$, then $K_n x = -x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K_2=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1}$ is indefinite. In fact, every commutation matrix except $K_1$ is indefinite. In particular, for every $\mathcal I=\{(j-1)n+i,\ (i-1)n+j\}$ with $i\ne j$, its principal submatrix
$$
A(\mathcal I,\mathcal I)=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}
$$
is indefinite.